# Add CSS class in Vue JS based on v-for followed by v-if

Tags: vue.js

Vue JS:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
results: {
  device: [{
    deviceName: "",
    info: [{value: ""}]
  }]
}
```

index.html:

```
<tr v-for="device in results.device" >

    <td>{{device.deviceName}}</a></td>

    <!--:class="{ false: v-for='info in device.info' !info.value }"-->

    <td v-for="info in device.info" :class="{ false: !info.value }">{{info.value}}
    </td>

</tr>
```

There are 2 td here.

For the 1st td, the required values are being displayed but I want the device to be highlighted based on the values returned from info.value.

> Anywhere you see true that td cell should not be highlighted. But even if 1 column value in a row has false that value along with the device name should be highlighted.

I was trying to implement that using the code that is commented, binding that class on the 1st td.

However, that syntax seems wrong.

What I want is the entire tr getting highlighted based on the values from info.value.

The 2nd td works as expected.

So, I need help with the 1st td or the wrapping tr.

Comment: why `info: [{value: ""}]` in array? is that have multile values? if that single value use `info: {value: ""}`

Comment: Yes, it does have multiple values

Comment: can u give sample data of `device` array. then i can give u solution.

Comment: "device":[{"deviceName":"devicename1","info":[{"value":false},{"value":""}]}

Comment: Also, the td having true values should not be highlighted

Comment: do you mean if all `value` false that row  to be highlighted... if that row have any one of the `value`true has to be ignored?

Comment: still i am not clear about your question. check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoYwyX and update. If its what u need then i post as answer.

Comment: check this codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRgYXB rows are hightlighted only if all values are `false'

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. The last codepen is almost perfect. Anywhere you see true that td cell should not be highlighted. But even if 1 column value in a row has false that value along with the device name should be highlighted.

Comment: check now. Thanks for the clarification. updated the codepen and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anywhere you see true that td cell should not be highlighted. But even if 1 column value in a row has false that value along with the device name should be highlighted.

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRgYXB

add a method to check all values are false

```
methods:{
  flasecond(index){
    let res = false
     this.results.device[index].info.forEach(info=> {
        if(!info.value) res = true
    })
      return res
  }
}
```

and in html

```
 <tr v-for="(device, index) in results.device"  >
  <td :class="{'falseclass' : flasecond(index)}">{{ device.deviceName }}</td>
  <td v-for="info in device.info" :class="{'falseclass' : !info.value}">{{info.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the column data sorted, based on clicking the table header of any column, currently referring to the link : https://www.raymondcamden.com/2018/02/08/building-table-sorting-and-pagination-in-vuejs, however that gives "TypeError: this.results.sort is not a function"

Comment: post a new question with codepen or jsfiddle which reproduce the error. i will try to fix

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513917/vue-js-2-sort-table-td-on-click-of-th