# Vue JS 2 Sort table td on click of th

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to sort the data of a HTML table based on the click of a table header in a table row using Vue JS 2.

I have implemented the sorting of 1st column. However, for some reason, maybe some syntax issue, the sorting for the rest of the columns do not work.

In the HTML, the parameters to the sort function looks problematic to me.

```
<th v-for="(toolAttribute, index) in results.toolAttribute" :key="index" @click="sort('info.value')" class="header">{{toolAttribute.attributeName}}</th>
```

The thing to look into the JS file:

```
computed:{
    sortedResults:function() {
      return this.results.device.sort(function(a,b){
        let modifier = 1;
        if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
        if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
        if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier;
        return 0;
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
```

Specifically:

```
return this.results.device.sort(function(a,b)
```

Here's the fiddle for the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/48x9wnud/

Comment: I think you can easily use DataTable Component provided by Vuetify. Here's the [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables).

Comment: It seems it would be a significant rewrite of the code with Vuetify

Comment: pls define what is comes first? `[{value: false}, {value: false}, {value: false}] or [{value: true}, {value: false}, {value: true}]`, in your current example this is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some undefined behaviour passing `info.value` into `{info:[{value: true}, ...]}` fixing this by passing arrays:

```
sort(['deviceName'])
```

or

```
sort(['info', index, 'value'])
```

and in `Array.sort` method iterate and self assign over passed values:

```
function(a,b){

    let modifier = 1;
    if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
    this.currentSort.forEach(x => {

       a = a[x];
       b = b[x];
    })

    if(a< b) return -1 * modifier;
    if(a > b) return 1 * modifier;

    return 0;

}
```

solution:

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
results: {
  toolAttribute: [{attributeName: "Present"},{attributeName: "Present"},{attributeName: "Present"}],
  device: [
    {deviceName: "Device Name 1",
      info: [{value: true}, {value: false}, {value: true}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 2",
      info: [{value: false}, {value: false}, {value: false}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 3",
      info: [{value: true}, {value: true}, {value: true}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 4",
      info: [{value: false}, {value: true}, {value: false}]},
    {deviceName: "Device Name 5",
      info: [{value: true}, {value: true}, {value: true}]}
     ]
},
currentSort:['deviceName'],
currentSortDir:'asc'
},
computed:{
    sortedResults:function() {
      return this.results.device.sort(function(a,b){
        let modifier = 1;
        if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
        this.currentSort.forEach(x => {
        
           a = a[x];
           b = b[x];
        })
        
        if(a< b) return -1 * modifier;
        if(a > b) return 1 * modifier;
        return 0;
      }.bind(this));
    }
  },
  methods:{
  flasecond(index){
    let res = false
     this.results.device[index].info.forEach(info=> {
        if(!info.value) res = true
    })
      return res
  },
  sort:function(s) {
      //if s == current sort, reverse
      if(s.join('') === this.currentSort.join('')) {
        this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
      }
      this.currentSort = s;
    },
}
})
```

```css
.falseclass{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}

.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table >
 <tr>
 <th rowspan="2" @click="sort(['deviceName'])" class="header">Device Info</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th v-for="(toolAttribute, index) in results.toolAttribute" :key="index" @click="sort(['info', index, 'value'])" class="header">{{toolAttribute.attributeName}}</th>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="(device, index) in sortedResults"  >
  <td :class="{'falseclass' : flasecond(index)}">{{ device.deviceName }}</td>
  <td v-for="info in device.info" :class="{'falseclass' : !info.value}">{{info.value}}</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: How can the font awesome icons be added here based on the asc or desc direction?

Comment: Like any component  - v-if asc v-else-if desc etc

Comment: That shows the asc/desc icons for every column, which means something is missing here

Comment: And both icons should be there as default.